# Ionic 2 set single component to md

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, hybrid

Is it possible to set a single component in a page to a certain platform.

For example, I have an iOS screen and I want the bottom toolbar just for this one page to use the Android Style (material design).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible every component in Ionic can be configured on 3 levels Global, Platform and Component level. To make that particular Toolbar component use Android Material Design Style no matter what platform it is, you can use the "*mode*" attribute and set it to **md**.

```
<ion-toolbar mode="md">
  <ion-title>Scrolls with the content</ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>
```

You can also configure to Windows with **wp** and IOS with **ios** values for the mode attribute. 
See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/toolbar/Toolbar/ for more details.